# Silverlight Application Development : Custom UI Form Development Beginner Question

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, solution-package, silverlight, xaml-browser-application

So I am new to SP Dev, and completely new to the idea of developing Silverlight applications, and the use of Expression. But I am trying to understand how Expression gets used with Visual Studio in order to develop an app (Sandbox Solution at that) for Sharepoint 2010.

From what I read it seems that the basic idea is that I can us Expression to Build UI elements for something like a form, then take that to Visual Studio to add functionality, create the package and upload to solution gallery. Is that correct (nutshell I realize)? What actually goes from Expression to Visual Studio, just the XAML?

Any help with understanding/context is greatly appreciate; for that matter all help I get here is always greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Silverlight development doesn't have direct relationship with SharePoint. But yes, you can use Silverlight as the main UI technology of your SharePoint solution, even the Silverlight development is standalone. http://www.silverlight.net is a good place to learn more about Silverlight development.
2. SharePoint 2010 provides a specific Client Object Model for Silverlight application. With this Silverlight Client Object Model, you can write code within a Silverlight application to interact with SharePoint site data. Please check this [url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538971.aspx) for more information about Silverlight Client Object Model.
3. When you put a Silverlight application in a SharePoint page, it's about SharePoint development now. What you need to do is creating a SharePoint solution to host the Silverlight application, or just use the out-of-box Silverlight Web Part to host the Silverlight application (see [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/add-silverlight-to-a-page-using-the-silverlight-web-part-HA101785161.aspx)).
4. There is some security consideration when you host a Silverlight application in a SharePoint page, please check [the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798413) on MSDN to get detail information.

And, there is a free book chapter on MSDN you can reference. [Chapter 14: Silverlight and SharePoint Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701782.aspx) . Microsoft also provides a training course about this topic, [SharePoint and Silverlight Training Course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandsilverlighttrainingcourse.aspx).

Comment: @kaneboy...wow thanks for all the references and information! appreciate it...these are great!